# Show Row Per Page in pagination

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, pagination

I have a pagination code from Mui and how can i add show per page dropdown button.

```
   <Pagination
        style={{
          marginLeft: "auto",
          marginTop: 20,
          display: "inline-block",
        }}
        count={Math.ceil(totalCount / TABLE_LIMIT)}
        boundaryCount={1}
        page={Number(pageNumber)}
        variant="outlined"
        shape="rounded"
        onChange={page}
      />
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a "show per page" dropdown button to your pagination, you can make use of the Material-UI Select component. Here's how you can modify your code to achieve this:

First, import the necessary components from Material-UI:

```
import { Pagination, Select, MenuItem } from '@mui/material';
```

Next, you can create a state variable to keep track of the number of items to show per page:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

// ...

const YourComponent = () => {
  // State variable to keep track of items per page
  const [itemsPerPage, setItemsPerPage] = useState(10); // Default value is 10, you can change it as needed

  // ... Rest of your code ...

  return (
    <div>
      {/* Pagination component */}
      <Pagination
        style={{
          marginLeft: 'auto',
          marginTop: 20,
          display: 'inline-block',
        }}
        count={Math.ceil(totalCount / itemsPerPage)}
        boundaryCount={1}
        page={Number(pageNumber)}
        variant="outlined"
        shape="rounded"
        onChange={page}
      />

      {/* Show per page dropdown */}
      <Select
        style={{ marginLeft: 20 }}
        value={itemsPerPage}
        onChange={(event) => setItemsPerPage(event.target.value)}
      >
        <MenuItem value={10}>10 per page</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={20}>20 per page</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={50}>50 per page</MenuItem>
        {/* Add more options as needed */}
      </Select>
    </div>
  );
};

export default YourComponent;
```

With this code, you'll have a "show per page" dropdown next to your pagination, allowing users to select how many items they want to see per page. You can adjust the MenuItem values and labels to provide different options based on your requirements.

Comment: this is changing my count number but number of rows displayed in table are same